# Dynamic row in magento admin form with generic class

Tags: magento2, adminform, dynamic-rows

I am trying to add dynamic row using generic form class and it show like below.
[image]

But the problem is that this value is not posting data.

Here is how i have implemented this.
`DynamicDiscount.php`

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

/**
 * Class AdditionalEmail
 */
class DynamicDiscount extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('discount_label', ['label' => __('Discount Label'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->addColumn('discount_per', ['label' => __('Percentage'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add New Row');
    }


}
```

`Form.php` and `_prepareLayout` function

```
    $layoutBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\DynamicDiscount::class
        );

        $fieldsetRow = $form->addFieldset('discount_update', ['legend' => __('Layout Updates')]);
$fieldsetRow->addField('discount_data', 'note', []);
        $form->getElement('discount_update')->setRenderer($layoutBlock);
```

can anyone guide me please how to post this data and save in custom table and make it populated in form when edit it.

Comment: How Can I store this data to database and to show that data in Edit form? Please suggest.

Comment: You can serialized and save

Comment: Thanks, I was able to serialize and save. Also able to show in Edit page. Now I have issue in delete buttons are not working for already loaded rows from database. If I add new then I am able to delete row. I get queryselector error for those rows delete button ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the full answer it may help someone.Might there is some good solution but for now it works.Please feel free to answer better solution.

in the `Form.php` `_prepareLayout` function should be extended from `\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic`

```
    $fieldsetRow = $form->addFieldset('discount_update', ['legend' => __('Discount Part')]);
        $dynamicRow = $fieldsetRow->addField('discount_data', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'discount_data',
            'required'  => false,
        ))->setRenderer($layoutBlock);
/* set data here when edit from your custom table */
        $dynamicRow->setValue(array(array('discount_label'=>'4545','discount_per'=>'45')));
```

Then create renderer file in my case it is
`DynamicDiscount.php`

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

/**
 * Class DynamicDiscount
 */
class DynamicDiscount extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('discount_label', ['label' => __('Discount Label'), 'class' => 'required-entry  admin__control-text']);
        $this->addColumn('discount_per', ['label' => __('Percentage'), 'class' => 'required-entry validate-digits-range digits-range-1-100 admin__control-text']);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add New Row');
    }


}
```

Comment: How to show saved data in the grid there?

Comment: `$dynamicRow->setValue(array(array('discount_label'=>'4545','discount_per'=>'45')));` by setting this to form

Comment: @Zaheerabbas Thanks for your answer and it is working as expected. My doubt is how can we add drag and drop to change the position in this dynamic rows ?

Comment: @Zaheerabbas Above solution showing me dynamic rows in form but not getting in Save.php controller in getPostData. How can I get data in Save.php?

Answer (score 2):

You should add `name` as config param when using `addField` and also you called `setRenderer` on fieldset element , if you check post request in console you'll see that values are passed but without name so you can't pick them up with `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` in controller, here's how it should look like:

```
        $fieldsetRow = $form->addFieldset(
            'discount_update',
            [
                'legend' => __('Layout Updates')
            ]
        );
        $fieldsetRow->addField(
            'discount_data',
            'note',
            [
                'name'=> 'discount_data' // element name so it can be properly passed with request
            ]
        )->setRenderer($layoutBlock);
```

**\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset::addField** passes back
**\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement** instance on which you can call `setRenderer` directly, so you can skip `$form->getElement('discount_data')->setRenderer($layoutBlock);`

If for whatever reason you do need to call it like that, make sure that you are passing **field id** and not the **fieldset id**, in your example field id would be `discount_data`

Comment: Yes this worked but now how to save and  setdata when edit form and populate with saved data.I have tried with this `$form->addValues(
                [
                    'id' => $customerGroup->getId(),
                    'customer_group_code' => $customerGroup->getCode(),
                    'tax_class_id' => $defaultCustomerTaxClass,
                   "discount_data['discount_data']" =>   ['discount_label'=>'4545','discount_per'=>'45']
                ]
            );` but not populated in form

Comment: That's an entirely different question, I don't know what exactly are you doing with it, is it a custom entity or are you extending some core feature, in either case you would need set data to model and save it

Comment: Yes true I am adding this feature to `customer_group` form and in that value is populating with `addValues` function.I have already set but not working

Answer (score 0):

Add Class as below to render dynamic rows section:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

/**
 * Class AdditionalEmail
 */
class DynamicDiscount extends AbstractFieldArray
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('discount_label', ['label' => __('Discount Label'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->addColumn('discount_per', ['label' => __('Percentage'), 'class' => 'required-entry']);
        $this->_addAfter = false;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add New Row');
    }
}
```

Form.php and _prepareLayout function

```
$fieldsetRow = $form->addFieldset(
        'discount_update',
        [
            'legend' => __('Layout Updates')
        ]
    );
    $fieldsetRow->addField(
        'discount_data',
        'note',
        [
            'name'=> 'discount_data' // element name so it can be properly passed with request
        ]
    )->setRenderer($layoutBlock);
```

Now to display dynamic rows data after save in edit form you need to set data in registry for dynamic rows field in edit controller action as below:

```
 $discountData['_0'] = [
     'discount_label'=>'4545',
     'discount_per'=>'45'
];
$discountData['_1'] = [
     'discount_label'=>'4646',
     'discount_per'=>'46'
];
$formData['discount_data'] = $discountData;
$this->_registry->register($formData);
```