# How to add dynamic rows with drag and drop option in generic php form?

Tags: magento2, adminform, dynamic-rows

I am trying to create a drag and drop dynamic rows field in admin php forms.

I created that form using `"Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory"`

I can able to create a normal field like below code

```
$fieldset->addField(
            'custom_field',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'custom_field',
                'label' => __('Custom Field'),
                'required' => true,
                'values' => $this->pageLayoutBuilder->getPageLayoutsConfig()->toOptionArray(),
            ]
        );
```

But I am unable to create a drag and drop dynamic row field. I have checked the field type classes in `"Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\"` path.

In the above path the all element type classes placed, but here I can found something like dynamic row or drag and drop field.

I have tried the below linked answer and it is working as dynamic rows, but drag and drop option is not working. How can I achieve drag and drop with dynamic rows field in php form ?

[Dynamic rows field in admin php form](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319613/dynamic-row-in-magento-admin-form-with-generic-class)

**Note: I am not using ui components. I need dynamic row drag and drop field without using ui component.**